# Magento - Color picker in front-end input

Tags: magento-1.7, frontend, color-picker

Anyone can help me how to add a color picker for a input field in front end. in Javascript folder the color picker script was there how we use that. otherwise help me to add a new color picker Javascript in magento.

Thank you

Comment: You can get started with one of the options and if stuck, post a more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty, [jPicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) being one of them. There are more options [in this blog post](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/). All of them should be compatible with magento.